# HTML 5 callback, handle row after insert

Tags: html, sqlite, cordova

I need generated id after insert query.
My transaction is like this:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Water( UserName,Password,Destination,Drinked,Time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',[user.UserName,user.Password,destination,0,bugun()],
     function(){},function(){statu=true;});
   });
    }
```

Is there a way get to inserted row without 'select' it? `//not like 'select last row from..'`

Comment: Use [built-in function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) `SELECT last_insert_rowid()`

Comment: WebSQL has [insertId](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#database-query-results) for this.

Comment: Thank both of you. I think insertId lokks better. Faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [CL.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11654/cl)

Answer:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO Water( UserName,Password,Destination,Drinked,Time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',[user.UserName,user.Password,destination,0,bugun()],
         function(s,result){return result.insertId;},function(){return false;});
         });
```

Comment: Please note that `return` in a callback function will just return from that callback, not from the outer function.